# Change joomla 2.5 default editor in custom component

Tags: joomla, editor, joomla2.5

I am using jce editor in my joomla and it's my default editor.
now I want use tinymce editor in my custom component at frontend Without changing the default editor. I get editor by this code:

```
  $editor = JFactory::getEditor();
  echo $editor->display('content', $this->content, '550', '400', '60', '20', false);
```

but it's only show my default editor. I want only use tinymce in my custom component fronted.

Answer (score 1):

First of all getEditor() is deprecated and you should not be using it for new code. Please review the docblocks and as instructed use JEditor instead.

If you read the docblocks you will see that the name of the editor is a property of the editor object. By default the constructor uses `'none'` but you can put what you want.

However, more importantly, in your xml form (as illustrated in com_templates) you can specify the editor

```
<field
    name="source"
    type="editor"
    editor="codemirror|none"
    buttons="no"
    label="COM_TEMPLATES_FIELD_SOURCE_LABEL"
    description="COM_TEMPLATES_FIELD_SOURCE_DESC"
    height="500px"
    rows="20"
    cols="80"
    syntax="php"
    filter="raw" />
```

Make sure you check that the editor is present and enabled, otherwise fall back to none.

Comment: thank you I want use editor in my fronted and custom form. your code for backend

Comment: There is no difference in form code between the front end and back end. But if you want to use `JEditor('tinymce')` that will work.

Comment: how can use JEditor method? i haven't xml file in front end

Comment: JFactory::getEditor() not have JEditor method

Comment: thank you i found how can use it. it's work with this code: $editor =& JFactory::getEditor('tinymce');

Comment: For anyone still wondering what's the correct code then it is `JEditor::getInstance('tinymce')` instead of `JFactory::getEditor('tinymce')`